# Using a stored procedure in Teradata to build a summarial history table

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, teradata

I am using Terdata SQL Assistant connected to an enterprise DW. I have written the query below to show an inventory of outstanding items as of a specific point in time. The table referenced loads and stores new records as changes are made to their state by load date (and does not delete historical records). The output of my query is 1 row for the specified date. Can I create a stored procedure or recursive query of some sort to build a history of these summary rows (with 1 new row per day)? I have not used such functions in the past; links to pertinent previously answered questions or suggestions on how I could get on the right track in researching other possible solutions are totally fine if applicable; just trying to bridge this gap in my knowledge.

```
SELECT
'2017-10-02' as Dt
,COUNT(DISTINCT A.RECORD_NBR) as Pending_Records 
,SUM(A.PAY_AMT) AS Total_Pending_Payments
FROM DB.RECORD_HISTORY A 

INNER JOIN
(SELECT MAX(LOAD_DT) AS LOAD_DT
,RECORD_NBR
FROM DB.RECORD_HISTORY
WHERE  LOAD_DT <= '2017-10-02' 
GROUP BY RECORD_NBR
) B 

ON A.RECORD_NBR = B.RECORD_NBR
AND A.LOAD_DT = B.LOAD_DT
WHERE 
A.RECORD_ORDER =1 AND Final_DT Is  Null   
GROUP BY Dt
ORDER BY 1 desc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my interpretation of your query:

> For the most recent load_dt (up until 2017-10-02) for record_order #1,
>   return
>
> 1) the number of different pending records
>   2) the total amount of pending payments

Is this correct?  If you're looking for this info, but one row for each "Load_Dt", you just need to remove that INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT 
    load_Dt,
    COUNT(DISTINCT record_nbr) AS Pending_Records,
    SUM(pay_amt) AS Total_Pending_Payments
FROM DB.record_history
WHERE record_order = 1
AND final_Dt IS NULL
GROUP BY load_Dt
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

If you want to get the summary info per record_order, just add record_order as a grouping column:

```
SELECT 
    load_Dt,
    record_order,
    COUNT(DISTINCT record_nbr) AS Pending_Records,
    SUM(pay_amt) AS Total_Pending_Payments
FROM DB.record_history
WHERE final_Dt IS NULL
GROUP BY load_Dt, record_order
ORDER BY 1,2 DESC
```

If you want to get one row per day (if there are calendar days with no corresponding "load_dt" days), then you can SELECT from the sys_calendar.calendar view and LEFT JOIN the query above on the "load_dt" field:

```
SELECT cal.calendar_date, src.Pending_Records, src.Total_Pending_Payments
FROM sys_calendar.calendar cal
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        load_Dt,
        COUNT(DISTINCT record_nbr) AS Pending_Records,
        SUM(pay_amt) AS Total_Pending_Payments
    FROM DB.record_history
    WHERE record_order = 1
    AND final_Dt IS NULL
    GROUP BY load_Dt
) src ON cal.calendar_date = src.load_Dt
WHERE cal.calendar_date BETWEEN <start_date> AND <end_date>
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

I don't have access to a TD system, so you may get syntax errors.  Let me know if that works or you're looking for something else.

Comment: Thank you for this; your final suggestion gets me the needed output without the need for further complexity (ie. a stored procedure)

Comment: No prob bob  :) .